# Java ME: How to flip svg image horizontally/vertically?

Tags: java, java-me, matrix, svg

The most helpfull result from google is [this](http://www.tinyline.com/forum/index.php?topic=59.0), but there are no `scale()` with two arguments in class SVGMatrix in JavaME that could be an analogous for this:

```
TinyMatrix transform = (TinyMatrix) node.getAttribute(SVG.ATT_TRANSFORM);
transform.scale(-(1<<Tiny2D.DFIX_BITS), 1<<Tiny2D.DFIX_BITS );
```

May be it is possible to do something with defining my own matrix for flipping and then use `mMultiply()` method, but I also could not find examples in net.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved it myself, flip is possible to do with embeded SVG-properties:

```
SVGImage svgImage = (SVGImage) this.frames.elementAt(i);
Document doc = svgImage.getDocument();
SVGSVGElement svg = (SVGSVGElement) doc.getDocumentElement();
SVGElement image = (SVGElement) doc.getElementById("image");
SVGElement group = (SVGElement) doc.createElementNS(SVG_NAMESPACE_URI, "g");
group.appendChild(image);
group.setTrait("transform", "translate(200,200) scale(-1,1)");
svg.appendChild(group);
```